# How to cache knitr chunks across two (or more) files?

Tags: r, knitr

I want to use some R-Code in two different *.Rnw files and want to use caching across those files.
I read http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/externalization/

Caching in one file just works fine. But running the second one the whole code is executed again:

plain.R

```
## @knitr random1
a <- rnorm(10)
a
```

doc1.Rnw (and doc2.Rnw)

```
\documentclass{article}

<<set-options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
 options(replace.assign=TRUE)
 opts_chunk$set(external=TRUE, cache=TRUE, echo=FALSE, fig=TRUE)
 read_chunk('plain.R')
@

\title{Doc 1}

\begin{document}

<<random1>>=
@

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to share the cache across several documents?

Comment: Not sure about `knitr`, but you might give a try to `pander::Pandoc.brew`: http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#caching with `evalsOptions('cache', 'disk')`

Comment: I'm building my environment upon knitr. So before switching to another mechanism I'd like to know that the way I used to go won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible to reuse the cache across multiple source documents. Please read the [cache page](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache) carefully to understand when cache will be rebuilt. In your case, the cache is not supposed to be rebuilt unless your two documents have different chunk options (condition 1), or different `getOption('width')` (condition 3), since your code remains the same (condition 2).

You have to post a reproducible example, otherwise this is not considered a real question.

Comment: You're right. As I mentioned below I thought I had posted a reproducible example. But I guess the problem occured because of some spaces used for indentation. I've read the manual page you've mentioned and therefor thought that the cache should be reusible -- and it is! ;-) Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

After completely resetting the example it turned out that the cache is reused by both files. I'm not sure what caused the problem before ....

But in a bigger project the chunks are not cached. So I'm not sure what causes the problem - maybe just a different count of spaces ....