# Share old knitr cache with new .Rnw files

Tags: r, knitr

I'm writing two reports (example1.Rnw and example2.Rnw, say) with cached chunks in the first that I'd like to be able to access and use in the second document.

Suppose example1.Rnw is

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\begin{document} 
<<simpleExample, cache=TRUE>>=
  z<-1+1
@
\end{document}
```

Then I thought example2.Rnw would be something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
<<setup>>=
 opts_chunk$set(cache.path = "~/DirectoryOfExample1/cache")
@
<<simplePrint, dependson = 'simpleExample'>>=
  print(z)
@
\end{document}
```

This seems similar to this question [How to cache knitr chunks across two (or more) files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503843/how-to-cache-knitr-chunks-across-two-or-more-files) except that I'm not using externalisation.  Is it possible to resuse an old cache in a new document this way, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to reuse a cache but IMHO you have to replicate you `simpleExample` chunk in your *example2.Rnw* file. It have to be exactly the same as in *example1.Rnw* (no different spaces, no different options, ...).

example2.Rnw:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
<<setup>>=
 opts_chunk$set(cache.path = "~/DirectoryOfExample1/cache")
@
<<simpleExample, cache=TRUE>>=
  z<-1+1
@
<<simplePrint, dependson = 'simpleExample'>>=
  print(z)
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: That solves my problem, thanks.  It'd be prefereable not to have to copy across the chunks from the 1st document into the 2nd purely to remove the chance of accidental changes to the cache.  Is there any way to inhibit any changes to the cache by the 2nd doc, effectively give it 'read-only' access to the cache?

Comment: I don't know any 'read-only' option. Maybe you should externalize your code, too?