# Caching knitr external code from multiple Rmd files

Tags: r, caching, knitr

I'm having difficulty getting knitr to utilize caching between two Rmd documents sharing common source code in an external R file.  Although I can see in the file system that both documents are writing output to the same set of cache files, each time one Rmd document is knitted to HTML it overwrites the cache files created when the previous Rmd was knitted.  Multiple knits of the same Rmd file successfully utilize the cache without re-executing the shared code.  Have I missed something in configuring the cache options for support of multiple documents?

Sample code and sessionInfo() dump are below.  Thanks in advance for any assistance you can offer.

**test1.R**

```
## @knitr source_chunk_1
x <- Sys.time()
x
```

**test1a.Rmd**

````
```{r set_global_options, cache=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(self.contained = FALSE)
opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE, cache.path = "knitrcache/test-")
read_chunk("test1.R")
```

```{r local_chunk_1, ref.label="source_chunk_1"}
```
````

**test1b.Rmd**

````
```{r set_global_options, cache=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(self.contained = FALSE)
opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE, cache.path = "knitrcache/test-")
read_chunk("test1.R")
```

```{r local_chunk_1, ref.label="source_chunk_1"}
```
````

**sessionInfo**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252           
LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
other attached packages:
[1] knitr_1.5
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] evaluate_0.5.3   formatR_0.10     rmarkdown_0.2.05 stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.0
```

Comment: I have to admit I would never have expected this to work in the first place -- it would be nice if it did, but I don't think it was designed that way ... ? (Can you point to documentation that suggests it *should* be expected to work?)  I would probably fall back to a manual system of saving and loading files (probably making the logical 'chunks' larger so as not to be loading and saving bits every few lines ...)

Comment: Yihui's comments in response to an earlier post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503843/how-to-cache-knitr-chunks-across-two-or-more-files?rq=1) indicate that it can be done.  I also read http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/  to mean it's possible.  the ref.label option (http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/) appears to have been created specifically to aid in doing this.  Checking the knitr source code, the issue seems to hinge on the creation of a hash code for the cache.  Not sure why the sample code above cause the hash to change and the cache to be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading and hacking around in the knitr source from github, I believe I've found the source of the problem.  Code in block.R sets the hash for the cache by calling the digest() function with the contents and options of the code chunk being processed:

```
hash = paste(valid_path(params$cache.path, label), digest::digest(content), sep = '_')
```

I temporarily inserted code to write out the data stored in the content object for each of my sample Rmd scripts above.  The default fig.path option value was the only component of the content that differed between them.

```
 > content$fig.path
[1] "./test1a_files/figure-html/"  

> content$fig.path
[1] "./test1b_files/figure-html/"
```

Setting a global fig.path in each Rmd file caused the content objects and resulting hash values to be identical.  Now, when I knit the two Rmd files, the same cached value is used for both.

**Test1.R**

```
## @knitr source_chunk_1
x <- Sys.time()
x
```

**test1a.Rmd**

````
```{r set_global_options, cache=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(self.contained = FALSE)
opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE, cache.path = "knitrcache/test-", fig.path = "knitrfig/test-")
read_chunk("test1.R")
```

```{r local_chunk_1, ref.label="source_chunk_1"}
```
````

**test1b.Rmd**

````
```{r set_global_options, cache=FALSE}
library(knitr)
opts_knit$set(self.contained = FALSE)
opts_chunk$set(cache = TRUE, cache.path = "knitrcache/test-", fig.path = "knitrfig/test-")
read_chunk("test1.R")
```

```{r local_chunk_1, ref.label="source_chunk_1"}
```
````

Comment: I'm curious about why don't you place *common* chunks (like `set_global_options` from your example above) into separate documents, using `knitr`'s **child documents** feature: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child. If I understand correctly, it's similar to C language's `include` feature.